# Integral with Legendre Polynomial $\int x^2(P_l(x))^2dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, legendre-polynomials

I have the integral where $P_l$ is the $l$th legendre polynomial.
$$
\int^1_{-1}x^2\left(P_l(x)\right)^2dx
$$

I think the way to do this is by integration by parts but I am not sure how to start. I can compute this numerically but I want a general expression in terms of $l$.

Comment: One possible way to get rid of $x^2$ is with the identity $$(n+1)P_{n+1}(x) + nP_{n-1}(x) = (2n+1)xP_n(x)$$ and then when you square, orthogonality will only leave separte integrals in terms of $P_{n+1}(x)^2$ and $P_{n-1}(x)^2$.

Comment: @gt6989 Wow! very well done! Thank you very much! I will comment shortly with the answer for future users.

Comment: (that identity and the orthogonality come from the generating function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x) t^n$ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $$\int_{-1}^1P_mP_ndx=\frac{2}{2n+1}\delta_{mn}.$$Following @gt6989b's tip, for $l\ge 1$ your integral is $$\frac{1}{(2l+1)^2}\int_{-1}^1(lP_{l-1}+(l+1)P_{l+1})^2dx=\frac{2}{(2l+1)^2}\left(\frac{l^2}{2l-1}+\frac{(l+1)^2}{2l+3}\right).$$In the case $l=0$, this would be $\frac23$. Indeed, $P_0=1$ so the integral is $\int_{-1}^1x^2dx=\frac23$ as required.